# How do I undo the last git pull on master in my server

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, git-pull

I ran a git pull command on my master branch, which broke the web app. I want to return to the previous state, but I couldn't find a way to undo the last pull. Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+pull

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done anything else - try

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

or if you want to reset the branch

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

To get more insight into where you're going to move do

```
git reflog
```

and review HEAD@{n} references to find the one you need.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Answer (score 0):

1. `git pull origin master` ← oops this caused an error/unwanted result
2. `git reflog` ← find the commit sha of the previous command. [See More](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog)
3. `git reset --hard <sha from 2.>`